# How would I programmatically change the background color of a cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicolor

So my actual question is a bit more robust. I'm curious whether it's possible to change the background color of a cell programmatically, however it would be based on whether the cell was first, or second, etc.

I'm not sure this is even possible, but what I'm trying to achieve is a gradient effect utilizing the cells as they increase in number.

```
if (indexPath.row % 2)
    {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
    else
    {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    }
```

I've tried something like this to at least have the color alternate to see if I can figure out what to do next, but this has failed. Alternating doesn't seem to be the right option, but it might be the right way to start programming what I want to happen.

Comment: Yes, it's quite simple. Have you tried it? What issue are you having?

Comment: I've tried utilizing an if statement on the indexPath.row, but I'm not sure if that's right. I'm at a loss really. I'm glad to hear its simple however.

Comment: Update your question with what you have tried.

Comment: Where is this code? Provide more context.

Comment: Use  cell.backgroundColor instead of cell.contentView.backgorunfColor.

Comment: @rmaddy It's in the cellforrowatindexpath

Comment: It needs to be in the `willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath` method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `tableView` sends this message to its delegate just before it uses cell to draw a row, thereby permitting the delegate to customize the cell object before it is displayed. [for more info](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:)

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {
         cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
    else {
         cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: So is the alternation limited to two colors only? Could I use 3 or 4?

Comment: You can do the colors any way you wish. The answer simply mirrors your code. But do whatever you need based on the index path.

Comment: you can use as per your requirement @JamesChen

Comment: @rmaddy So can you provide an example of how I can use three colors? I've tried it all day.

Comment: One option is a simple `if/else if/else` block checking the row value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to change the background color of a cell programmatically, based on whether the cell was first, or second, etc. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method, check if row is odd then put the different background color, if it is even then put the different color. By using below code, you will get alternate colors of rows.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CommentTableCellIdentifier"];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Your text goes here";
    if(indexPath.row % 2 == 0)
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    else
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    return cell;
}
```

SWIFT:-

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?) -> UITableViewCell? {
    // Configure the cell...
    let cellId: NSString = "Cell"
    var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel.text = "Your text goes here"
    if(indexPath.row % 2 == 0)
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
    else
    {
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: The background color needs to be set in the `willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath` method, not the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. And the question is tagged Swift, not Objective-C. Post answers in the appropriate language.

Comment: This sort of worked as well, just trying to make 3 colors work as mentioned above, fiddling with the indexPath now.

Answer (score -1):

***Swift 4.2***

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if indexPath.row % 2 == 0 {

         cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
         //OR
         productCell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }
    else {

         cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }

    return cell
}
```